# MVC - Owin 2.0 Google Authentication fails when running in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, oauth-2.0, network-programming

The following error is what I encounter when trying to authenticate with Google on my MVC app after deploying to production with Visual Studio 2017 (see attachment).

Chrome Network inspect
[image: Chrome Network inspect]

Mention : It works with localhost perfectly. 
The server which runs  the IIS on behind a netscaler which does the port translation.
The app is set to run on SSL, as the IIS and the netscaler.

Is there a code workaround? Or another "easy" way to implement google authentication without using the MVC build-in OWIN ?

Comment: Have you provided you live domain url in google console.

Comment: hello, yes of course.